# Get value in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to get out value for everyone in this array.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => OrderItem Object ( 
        [description:protected] => 0987654321
        [unitPrice:protected] => 396.0000
        [quantity:protected] => 1.00
        [taxPercentage:protected] => 0.250000
        [sku:protected] => 212 
    )
)
```

Like, I want to get out 0987654321 or 396.0000 =)

How do I do?

I'm using a payment solution and trying to get out this.

This code: `$order = $details->getOrderItems();` and `print_r` will write out this array I have posted.

Variable `$details = $detailsResponse->getPaymentDetails();`

And the function getOrderItems looks like this:

```
public function getOrderItems() {
    return $this->orderItems;
}
```

Comment: So what methods are available to the OrderItem __Object__?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Are you working in Yii ?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. I'm using Payson (it's like paypal). I will update my question. =)

Comment: The `print_r` shows **protected** properties of the OrderItem object. Unless you create a `public function` to fetch them, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class have getters so you can try this:

```
$arrName[0]->getDescription();
```

You can view the whole class here:
https://github.com/PaysonAktiebolag/api-integration-php/blob/master/lib/orderitem.php

Answer (score 0):

The `print_r()` shows **protected** properties of the `OrderItem` object. Unless you create a public function to fetch them, you're out of luck.

For example, if you create a public function like;

```
public function getProtected($varName) {
  if( property_exists($this, $varName) ) {
     return $this->$varName;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

You will be able to get `protected` variables. Here's a quick demo: https://eval.in/318390

The reason you cannot call `$obj->description` is because of the [variable visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

If you tried to access the `protected` variable, you would see the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot access protected property OrderItem::$description`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFysv.jpg]